# C stack usage is too close to the limit

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, posixct

I am creating a web app using shiny package on R. I am taking 2 file inputs in the app. One of them is indexed by date and time info. (i.e. 01.04.2019 12:00:00). However, in the server side of the app, I have to convert this date and time column's type to POSIXct because it is read from excel as character. And when I do so and launch the app, immediately after uploading the data to the app, the app stops and gives the error ;
"C stack usage  7971264 is too close to the limit"
The code at the server that reads the uploaded file is;

```
usedata <- reactive ({
      file1 <- input$file
      if(is.null(file1)){return()}
      read.xlsx(xlsxFile = file1$datapath)
      as.POSIXct(usedata()$Date.and.Time, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
    })
```

When I comment out the as.POSIXct row, the code works fine but I cannot do the calculations I need to do because I need the month information of the "usedata". Is there any suggestions to this issue? Thanks for further help.

Comment: You are calling the function inside the function itself and you get an infinite loop. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: As Nicola states, the problem is not `as.POSIXct`, it's the fact that if `if.null(file1)` is `FALSE` then calling `usedata()` from within `usedata()` will never end. It will repeatably call the function infinitely. Likely what you were looking for is to change `read.xlsx(...)` to `file <- read.xlsx(...); as.POSIXct(file$Date.and.Time, ...)`

Comment: Thanks both Nicola and Oliver. I understand the problem you mention. However, I could not understand the solution you suggest Oliver. I would be really pleased if you could write the code explicitly. By the way the read.xlsx function I'm using is from openxlsx package. Thanks for further help

Comment: @AhmetÜnler Oliver provided the code explicitly. When you call `read.xlsx` assign the result to a variable (Oliver named it `file`) and in the following line you change `usedata()` with `file` (or the name you choose for that variable).

Comment: When I convert the code as you mentioned above, I get an error ; $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. I assume that' because the variable is created inside a reactive. What do you suggest?